# How to config dynamic multiple datasource with Spring boot JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to choose different datasource in run time, here is my example:
There are 2 same structure MySQL table in different databases, let's say testing.io:3306/db/person and production.io:3306/db/person. I want to choose the DB according to some criteria.

Here are some **pseudo** codes:

The entity class

```
@Entity
@Data
public class person{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

The repository of it:

```
   @RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "Person", path = "Person")
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long>{

}
```

The application.yml

```
 spring:
  datasource:
    testing:
      url: jdbc:mysql://testing.io:3306/db?useSSL=false
      username: root
      password: 1111
    production:
      url: jdbc:mysql://production.io:3306/db?useSSL=false
      username: root
      password: 2222
   driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

I omit the service interface because there is only one method in it.

The controller:

```
   @RestController
public class PersonrController {
    @Autowired
    PersonService personService ;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/select-person", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String selectPerson(@RequestBody parameter) {
        /**
          class Parameter only has one field: env
        /
        return personService.select(Parameter parameter);
    }


}
```

The service implement:

```
@Service
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService {
    @Autowired
    @Use("testing") // It means this repo uses the 'testing' config in the application.yml
    PersonRepository testingPersonRepo;

    @Autowired
    @Use("production") // It means this repo uses the 'production' config in the application.yml
    PersonRepository productionPersonRepo;


    @Override
    public String select(Parameter parameter){
        // dynamically use different DB with the same entity
        if (parameter.getEnv().equals("production")){
            return productionPersonRepo.findAll();
        }else{
            return testingPersonRepo.findAll();
        }

    }
}
```

How to config that with Spring Boot JPA **elegantly**?

Answer (score 1):

You should use spring profiles.
At the start of the application you tell the environment the variable `"spring.profiles.active"` to determine if it is a testing or a production, `spring.profiles.active=testing` or `spring.profiles.active=production`

Then in your `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: testing

spring:
  datasource:
      url: jdbc:mysql://testing.io:3306/db?useSSL=false
      username: root
      password: 1111
 driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

---
spring:
  profiles:
    active: production

spring:
  datasource:
      url: jdbc:mysql://production.io:3306/db?useSSL=false
      username: root
      password: 2222
```

This will assign your datasource the value depending on whether the profile is one or the other.

Comment: First of all , thanks for your answer. But I don't think you get my point. If I use profile , can I use both of the profiles' config in run time ? Please read my pseudo codes.

Comment: You cannot use two configs at runtime if this is what you are asking.